# Android Listview scrolling repeat numbers

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i have a edittext inside a listview and i want the user to put some numbers on it, and then  save that into a array...
But i have the scroll problem i saw others post and i could find a solution.

Problem: "hen i scroll the numbers repeat and change places.

My Adapter:

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private static ArrayList<Alimentos> searchArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Alimentos> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {      
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.amidos, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Alimentos);
            holder.txtQuant = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quant1);  
            holder.Quant = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_quant); 
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txtQuant.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getQuantidade());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtQuant;
        EditText Quant;
    }
}
```

My listrow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Alimentos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quant1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Alimentos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Alimentos"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_quant"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/quant1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quant1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Quantidade:"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="0" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My listview xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="1 porção ou equivalente (tem ± 12 g HC)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/niveL2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:text="Total de Hidratos de Carbono:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/insu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/niveL2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/niveL2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/insu"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/insu"
        android:text="HC"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/niveL2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hcalcu"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Total de Hidratos Consumidos" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's my first post thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) instead of a wall of code.

Comment: Check if your variable `position` has the correct values according to the position in the `ListView`. Sometimes that position value is relative to your current position (the first element you see is 0 or 1, the second 2 and so on).

Comment: @zozelfelfo i see positions just fine 0 to 30 with no erros...
in start i can only see 2 positions and if i put a number on position 0 and position 1 the list start to repeat on position 2...30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks i could find another way wit textWatcher i will post my solution here for other people:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {     
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.amidos, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Alimentos);
            holder.txtQuant = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quant1);  
            holder.Quant = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_quant);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txtQuant.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getQuantidade());

        if (holder.textWatcher != null) {
            holder.Quant.removeTextChangedListener(holder.textWatcher);
        }

        // Create the TextWatcher corresponding to this row
        holder.textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.toString().equals("")){
                    searchArrayList.get(position).setQua("0");
                }
                else{
                    searchArrayList.get(position).setQua(s.toString());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        };

        holder.Quant.addTextChangedListener(holder.textWatcher);

        Alimentos ali = searchArrayList.get(position);
        holder.Quant.setText(ali.getQua());


        return convertView;
    }

        static class ViewHolder {
            public TextWatcher textWatcher;
            TextView txtName;
            TextView txtQuant;
            EditText Quant;
        }
```

Comment: if my answer helped you you could at least give me my answer +1, or mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not saving the value you store in your `EditText` object.

When you scroll android reuses your old views in order to show you the new ones and your EditText will be reuses with the values you have inserted.

I recommend you to store the values in your `EditText` as soon as you lose focus, like the following.

```
 holder.Quant.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
           //store the value here
    }
});
```

After that you should load the `EditText` value as you do with your `TextView` objects.

```
holder.Quant.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getUserQuant());
```

This way you will be able to get the correct value at each row.

Hope it helps

Comment: dont work for me put it like this way:

[link] (http://pastebin.com/EXvdga7E)

am i doing something wrong?

Comment: you cannot save it in your `holder` variable, you have to save in in your `searchArrayList` variable or in other you may use.

Comment: but i need to use the values from edittext in activity to calc something? i am new on android

Comment: You only need to store them, then you can do whatever you want with them. You need to store them in order to load your `listview` rows as you do with your TextView.

If you see, everytime your `getView` method is called you are filling your `TextView` values, you have to do the same with your `EditText`, the problem is that the user can modify your `EditText` so everytime you lose focus on an `EditText` you store the current value in order to reload the rows correctly later on.

Comment: but how can i store it?

Comment: You need a set method, try something like the following: 

`searchArrayList.get(position).setUserQuant(holder.Quant.getText());`

Comment: done like you said [link](http://pastebin.com/dkMRfLSC) but i got a nullpointerExecption

Comment: Cant see pastebin from my office, I'll check it out this noon.